# Hows to force robocopy to produce less verbose output

Tags: robocopy

I have a short cmd file I run every day to back up any new or updated files/folders from sys1 onto sys2.  The line within that file that I use right now for the backup is:

start /w robocopy \sys1\data\ \sys2\data\ /s /xo

The files, folders and subfolders on sys1 and sys2 are identical, each with about 50,000 files and 5000 subfolders.  My problem is I only update 5-10 files per day, and when I run the cmd file it outputs every single subfolder as robocopy does its work, not just the files being updated.  I would like to see *only* the files that are copied, not all the subfolders not being updated.  Is this possible? Or if not, is there a small easy command line tool similar to robocopy I could use?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs: You can start to use `/ndl` and see if that suits you

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

[image]